# Rescue errors in terminal launched from script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu, gnome-terminal

I am using Ubuntu and made a short script on my Desktop. Double clicking it opens a terminal and starts my server.

This is all working fine except there's one problem. If there's an error raised in my server, the launched terminal immediately closes.

I want to keep the terminal open and show the error.

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

 gnome-terminal -e '/bin/bash -c "cd ~/Desktop/browser_tester/; ./start.sh" '
```

I'm using the advice from [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/473277/271123) to construct that command. I'm asking for a way to rescue errors inside the subprocess so that the `gnome_terminal` displays those errors and doesn't just exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the exit status.

```
./start.sh || read
```

This will wait for a keypress if the command failed.

Comment: thank you, this works well. I'm still curious to know if there's a way to return control to the terminal, i.e. allow subsequent user input.

Comment: `; bash` ... ? :)